# How do I make Stripe email a customer when they subscribe?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm using the Stripe's Python library to process subscriptions.

Here's a snippet of my backend code.

```
stripeCustomer= stripe.Customer.create(
    email=userInputtedEmail,
    source=stripeTokenSendFromFrontEnd,
)
```

The [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/receipts) mention the ability to email customers when they subscribe. But when I set up a form with a $0.01/day subscribtion to test this out, I got no emailed receipt. I'm not in Stripe's test mode, I'm in its live mode. There are no relevant errors in my Stripe Dashboard's Developers section.

How do I set Stripe up to email customers when they subscribe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've enabled email receipts upon **Successful Payments** in your [Dashboard Settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/emails), your user should see a receipt upon each subscription payment, including immediately after you create a subscription.

That said, the issue here has to do with the amount of your subscription. The Stripe [minimum charge amount](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#minimum-and-maximum-charge-amounts) is **$0.50**.

Since you're charging `$0.01/day` that amount will accrue in the Customer's [account balance](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object-account_balance) and will only be charged once it meets the $0.50 minimum (so in 50 days).

If you charge a minimum of $0.50, assuming no trial period, you should see this payment and receipt immediately upon subscription creation.